# Neo4j one-to-many fetch data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my Spring Boot/Neo4j application I have a following entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String HAS = "HAS";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @RelatedTo(type = HAS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

....

}


@NodeEntity
public class Vote extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String VOTED_ON = "VOTED_ON";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";
    private static final String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_FOR, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Criterion criteria;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;

    private double weight;

    private String description;


}
```

and I have a following SDN repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} RETURN v")
List<Vote> getVotes(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criterionId") Long criterionId);
```

In the result I have a list of `Vote`.

On the client I'd like to display list of these votes with not only user(author) `Id` but and with author `username` also.

How to fetch based on the query above `Vote.author.username` and `Vote.author.id` and do not fetch all other information from `User` entity associated with `Vote` entity? Anyway, right now I only have `Vote.author.id` value.

**EDITED:**

following query

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} WITH v, d, c MATCH v-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) RETURN {id: v.id, weight: v.weight, description: v.description, `decision.id` : d.id, `criterion.id` : c.id, `author.id`: u.id, `author.username`: u.username} as v")
List<Vote> getVotesForDecisionOnCriterion(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criterionId") Long criterionId);
```

doesn't work with a following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: [Assertion failed] - entity is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.ParameterCheck.notNull(ParameterCheck.java:29)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.projectTo(Neo4jTemplate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.doConvert(EntityResultConverter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.DefaultConverter.convert(DefaultConverter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.convert(EntityResultConverter.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.underlyingObjectToObject(QueryResultBuilder.java:86)
```

Comment: In SDN3 you cannot just create a map and have it pretend to be a NodeEntity, that's what @QueryResult annotated DTOs are for. See the docs.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having User as a member of Vote and at the same time as a separated entity in @QueryResult (Vote, User)..  I think that this is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with a DTO (can also be an interface with getters):

```
@QueryResult
class VoteView {
   String id;
   Double weight;
   String description;
   String decisionId;  
   String criterionId;  
   String authorId;
   String authorName;
}

@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} WITH v, d, c MATCH v-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) RETURN {id: v.id, weight: v.weight, description: v.description, decisionId : d.id, criterionId : c.id, authorId: u.id, authorName: u.username} as v")
List<VoteView> getVotesForDecisionOnCriterion(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criterionId") Long criterionId);
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine but with a following query(returns separeted columns, not map) @Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} WITH v, d, c MATCH v-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) RETURN v.id as voteId, d.id as decisionId, c.id as criterionId, v.weight as weight, v.description as description, u.id as authorId, u.username as authorName, v.createDate as createDate, v.updateDate as updateDate")
 List<AuthorVote> getVotesForDecisionOnCriterion(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criterionId") Long criterionId);

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the spring but does this cypher get you what you want?

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion)
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} 
  AND id(c) = {criterionId} 
WITH v
MATCH v-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
RETURN {id: v.id
       , weight: v.weight
       , `author.id`: u.id
       , `author.username`: u.username
       ... } as v
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will return two separated entities - Vote and String. But I'm looking for a solution, how to populate v.author.username with u.username from your query and return only "v"

Comment: i updated the answer and combined the properties into a single map... - not v though

Comment: Nice idea ! But I can't get it working with a following exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: [Assertion failed] - entity is required; it must not be null
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.ParameterCheck.notNull(ParameterCheck.java:29)
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.projectTo(Neo4jTemplate.java:240)
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.conversion.EntityResultConverter.doConvert(EntityResultConverter.java:73)

Comment: damn computers... so close...is one of the items null (i.e. returning a null value with a key in the map)?  If that is the problem you could coalesce the result or add a case statement to eliminate that key alltogether

Comment: I have updated my question body.. added full Vote class declaration, new query and error stacktrace

Comment: "RETURN {id: v.id} as v" also doesn't work with the same exception.. But this one "RETURN v" works perfectly .. Anyway, "v" can't be null

Comment: I also can use @Fetch annotation on "private User author" field.. but I'm not sure how it will work from the performance perspective..

Comment: It's not cheap. It's a n+1 fetch. The problem is that a map can't pretend to be a node-entity. Btw. Dave can you drop me an email to michael at neo4j.org ?