# How to return nodes and relationships with Neo4j spring data repository

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there any way to return somehow a list of {relationship,node} couples using spring data and cypher?

Ex:
Suppose I have the graph "User visited Cities":

```
(User 1) -[r1] -> (New York)
(User 1) -[r2] -> (Paris)
(User 1) -[r3] -> (Madrid)
```

What I want to find is (or similar structure):
Given the {user = "User 1"}, return :

```
[r1], (New York)
[r2], (Paris)
[r3], (Madrid)
```

PS :relationships has date property, that's why I want to return it with each city node.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with sdn, but cypher request is: `MATCH (u:User) -[r:VISITED]->(c:City) return r,c`, assuming your labels are User, City and your relation is VISITED

Comment: Thanks. I know already that. I'm just wondering how this will be mapped by sdn

Comment: here is a related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411926/neo4j-one-to-many-fetch-data/29414571#29414571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create a class and Annotate it like this :

```
@QueryResult
public class NodeAndRelationship {

    @ResultColumn("node")
    private Node node;
    @ResultColumn("rel")
    private Relationship rel;
//getters and setters
}
```